# copy of string in to a dynamic ui label

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

```
  NSString *city2=[[NSString alloc]init];
  city2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"the city orlando"];
  NSString *trimmedString = [city2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
  NSLog(@"%@", trimmedString)

   trimmedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ",trimmedString];

   CGSize constraint4 = CGSizeMake(650, 2000.0f);

  CGSize size4 = [city2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
   city = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];

   [city setNumberOfLines:0];
   city.frame = CGRectMake(150,codetype.frame.size.height+codetype.frame.origin.y, size4.width, size4.height);          
   [city setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",trimmedString]];
```

I am getting the city only instead of the city orlando *it is a small part in my project*.

actually i am assigning string to a label.but i did not get the total string in label.
here line3 is another `UILabel` which is above to the city label.

Comment: You mean you want "city orlando" str from "the city orlando",right?

Comment: Question is not clear .. Please elaborate.

Comment: What is your requirement? Make sure that you are making a clear idea of what you are asking.

Comment: no i want "the city orlando" in  city label. but iam getting only "the city      " after that some space is coming.

Comment: actually iam assigning string to a label.but i didnt get the total string in label.

Comment: Why you are allocated city2, while assigning in next line.
Why you are trimmedString already exist same, why you are again fomratted it.
Why again formatted in last line while taken size w.r.t city2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look's like the `city` label is to small to fit the text. There could be different issues for that, but maybe `city` label doesn't have **Helvetica 12** set, when you calculate `size4` with it. Note also, that you're getting the size of city2, but setting text to trimmedString.

```
CGSize size4 = [city2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

You may check it via

```
[city setColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

And see what happens.

Or, to check it fast replace

```
CGSize size4 = [city2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
city = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];
```

with

```
city = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];
CGSize size4 = [trimmedString sizeWithFont: city.font constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this -> **the city...** instead of this -> **the city orlando,**? Just increase the `size4.width` of your `UILabel` in the `city.frame` line, like this `size4.width + 100.0f`. This is my version of your code.

```
NSString *city2 = @"the city orlando";
NSString *trimmedString = [city2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];                                                                                                 
NSLog(@"%@", trimmedString);

trimmedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",trimmedString];

CGSize constraint4 = CGSizeMake(650, 2000.0f);

CGSize size4 = [city2 sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
city = [[UILabel alloc] init]; //(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];

[city setNumberOfLines:0];
city.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, size4.width + 100.0f, size4.height + 10.0f);


[city setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",trimmedString]];  

[self.view addSubview:city];
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire string is not visible in the label because the width of the `UILabel` is smaller compared to width of the string.
So increase the width of the `UILabel` your code will work fine.

Replace this code

```
city.frame = CGRectMake(150,codetype.frame.size.height+codetype.frame.origin.y, size4.width, size4.height);
```

by

```
city.frame = CGRectMake(150,codetype.frame.size.height+codetype.frame.origin.y, size4.width+100, size4.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with this code but the primary problem seems to be in your calculation of the string's size. You are getting the size of `city2` but then setting the label's text to `trimmingString`. Also, the font used for the calculation may be different than the label's font. Make them the same.

Here is your code with lots of cleanup and the fixes:

```
NSString *city2 = @"the city orlando";
NSString *trimmedString = [city2 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"%@", trimmedString)

trimmedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ", trimmedString];

CGSize constraint4 = CGSizeMake(650, 2000.0f);

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
CGSize size4 = [trimmedString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraint4 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
city = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:115];

city.font = font;
[city setNumberOfLines:0];
city.frame = CGRectMake(150, codetype.frame.size.height + codetype.frame.origin.y,  size4.width, size4.height);

[city setText:trimmedString];
```

Please avoid all of the extra calls to `stringWithFormat:`.